# How to resize ProgressBar in Flash CS5.

Tags: actionscript-3, progress-bar, flash-cs5

I am using 'ProgressBar' component in Flash CS5 to create the level-progress-bar of my game.
I know how to change color and size of the bar.
But I want to reshape the sharp edges at the end of the 'ProgressBar' to smooth round edges .
Is there a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to make your own level progress bar. [Component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa4.html).

Take a look [this](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/preloader_as3_pg1.htm).